# How to change context path of where beans are found

Tags: spring, tomcat, tomcat6, portlet, tcserver

I'm receiving this error when starting my app :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context.xml]

I don't know why Spring is searching for servlet-context.xml . All of my contexts are configured in web-inf/context/portlet
Is there a setting I can add to web.xml so tomcat can resolve the contexts from a different dir to /WEB-INF/spring/servlet/servlet-context.xml ? Or is another way of fixing this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you set the location of the context in your *WEB-INF/web.xml* file, see here:
 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#web-integration-common

So your *WEB-INF/web.xml* file should look something like, check carefully that the **contextConfigLocation** value points to your context configuration files:

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/context/portlet/*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```